# Como executar um código javascript recebido por uma requisição AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tenho esse código no banco de dados:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("teste script-1");
    var axel = Math.random() + "";
    var a = axel * 10000000000000;
    document.write('<iframe src="https:// .... ;ord=' + a + '?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>');
</script>
<noscript>
    <iframe src="https://...;ord=1?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>
</noscript>
```

Respondendo a alguns eventos (page load ou btn click), tenho uma função AJAX que vai ao banco de dados e recupera o script. Veja abaixo:

```
$.getJSON( "returnScript.php", {objEvent: btn_id}, function() {
            })
            .done(function(dataset) {          
                //console.log(dataset);                  
                //console.log(dataset.length);  
                if(dataset.length>0){
                    for (var index in dataset){ 
                        console.log(dataset[index].script);
                        $("body").append(dataset[index].script);
                    }                
                }
                else{
                  console.log("sem script para ser executado");
                }              
            });
```

Nesse código, após consultar o banco de dados, se existe algum script para ser executado (segundo os critérios) ele deverá recuperar todo o código a fazer um append antes de terminar a tag body. Como se vê acima, o códig possui uma parte script e uma parte iframe.

O fato é que se eu colar esse código na página ele finciona bem. Mas se eu usar `$("body").append(dataset[index].script);` o `alert("teste script-1");` executa corretamente mas o restante do código faz a página ficar toda branca (WSOD) com a seguinte mensagem no console do browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at (index):551
    at (index):551
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange ((index):551)
```

Claramente o que está acontecendo é que quando o código é recuperado pelo AJAX ele não funciona.

ALguém saberia como resolver isso?

Estou usando win7 + php5.3 + symfony.

Comment: Provavelmente seu problema é o `document.write` no script recuperado via ajax. Tente utilizar um `$('body').append('<iframe src="https:// .... ;ord=' + a + '?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>');`.

Comment: Correto. Quando rodamos `document.write` depois que o documento foi carregado essa fun sobrescreve todo o codigo, mas se ela rodar antes do documento ser carregado não sobrescreve. Como aqui no meu caso é um ajax, tenho que substituir `document.write()` por `$('body').append()`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941866/document-write-overwriting-the-document . Poste sua resposta para ganhar o ponto.

Comment: Exato. Esperei seu retorno para saber se era realmente o caso, antes de explicar o porquê isso acontece, já que os comentários não têm a finalidade nem espaço para algo mais elaborado. Vou responder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você utilizar o `document.write` após a página HTML ter sido carregada, o navegador vai sobrescrever o conteúdo atual pelo conteúdo do `document.write`.

No seu caso, quando você executa o ajax a página já foi carregada, então `document.write` do conteúdo da requisição assíncrona, que é inserido no body (`$("body").append(dataset[index].script);`), sobrescreve o documento inteiro.

Você pode substituir a chamada do `document.write` por:

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<iframe src="https:// .... ;ord=' + a + '?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>';
```

Como está utilizando jQuery na página que o código vai ser incorporado, pode usar também:

```
$('body').append('<iframe src="https:// .... ;ord=' + a + '?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>');
```